# Changing default values for properties (e.g. asynchronous)

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

For many applications, especially on low-performance machines, it is beneficial to have built-in components, such as `Loader` and `Image`, setup to load their resources asynchronously. To do this, there are two obvious options:

1. Set the required property of the built-in component, i.e. `asynchronous: true`
2. Create a custom component `AsyncXXX` with basically this content:

AsyncXXX.qml:

```
XXX {
    asynchronous: true
}
```

where XXX is either `Loader` or `Image`.

I wonder why they are not set to asynchronous mode by default.

Most importantly, is there a way - an environment variable, a global setting - to change the default behaviour of built-in components to the asynchronous one, thus avoiding custom components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could easily make `ASLoader` and `ASImage` QML types which are just `Loader` and `Image` with `asynchronous: true` and use those throughout your project. This will save you on having to modify it everywhere, and if you want to override that, you just go and change it in the prototype.

> I wonder why they are not set to asynchronous mode by default.

Asynchronous is always more complicated and with more overhead, so it makes sense if it is not the default behavior. From the QML code I've seen, synchronous is used much more often than asynchronous, so it will make very little sense to make asynchronous default.

EDIT:

You could also achieve switching between synchronous and asynchronous behavior during the runtime if you bind the prototype to a project-wide property, for example a context property, or a property in `main.qml`.